# Query MinIO database without converting the files with Pandas

Tags: minio, querying

I would like to know if there is any option available in order to query a MinIO database that stores DeltaTables in parquet format.

Currently I am using pyarrow with pandas but is really slow when the data become larger.
I saw that PySpark can be used to query the DeltaTables but I would like to know if there are any other options.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It could depend how big the scale of the data you are dealing with, for big enough data sets you could try using presto for SQL syntax queries of from a MinIO source parquet files, using Hive Connector here is a how to:

https://blog.min.io/interactive-sql-query-with-presto-on-minio-cloud-storage/

Also, when you hit a large dataset could take advantage of Hive partition folder naming convention (ie. s3://bucketname/year=2019/ )to reduce the size of the data set needed to be queried, [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html?highlight=partition#examples) is the docs regarding partitioning in in hive connector.

Unrelated note: credits to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60217005/presto-how-to-read-from-s3-an-entire-bucket-that-is-partitioned-in-sub-folders) for help me remember the convention name